# Rotate Board and Components in Altium

Tags: altium, board

Can I rotate the components and the board at once? I try hold click + Space bar but it just rotates the component only. Say I already have a 20mm x 10mm board size and I want to make it 10mm x 20mm. I tried Design >> Board Shape. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: " **View » Board Planning Mode**, commands that support interactively changing the shape are available in this mode:

    **Redefine Board Shape** - select this command to interactively draw a new shape.
    **Move Board Vertices** - select this command to interactively modify the shape of the board by moving vertices or sliding the edges of the shape. 
" 

Move Board Vertices would be the best for you as it allows to move the sides of the board. [AltiumTechDoc](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Obj-BoardShape%28%28Board+Shape%29%29_AD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **View » Board Planning Mode**, commands that support interactively
>   changing the shape are available in this mode:
>
> - **Redefine Board Shape** - select this command to interactively draw a new shape.
> - **Move Board Vertices** - select this command to interactively modify the shape of the board by moving vertices or sliding the edges
>     of the shape.
> - **Move Board Shape** - select this command to move the complete board shape to a new location in the workspace. Note that this command
>     only moves the board shape, other objects that have been placed in the
>     workspace are not moved. To move the board shape as well as all placed
>     objects, select everything to be moved and use the **Edit » Move »
>     Move Selection** command (switch to 2D Layout Mode first). Taken from
>     [Altium Tech Doc](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Obj-BoardShape%28%28Board+Shape%29%29_AD).

The **Move Board Shape** option will allow you to rotate the whole board(without the components) when the **Space Bar** is pressed. So I would like to correct my comment, this option does exactly what you need.

[image]

Nevertheless, the **Move Board Vertices** is pretty useful too.