# PCB Dimensions definition in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am designing a PCB to be cascaded to this PCB shown in the following picture.
I wonder how can I define the dimensions in Altium designer. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: When you create a new PCB doc, you can set the board dimensions in the wizard. Redefining it is described in this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241083/rotate-board-and-components-in-altium/241379#241379

Comment: @BenceKaulics this does not allow me to insert specific dimensions 53 cm x 140 cm...

Comment: You really want to creat roughly a 0.5 m x 1.5 m PCB? or you meant milimeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PCB Board Wizard with the following setting 530 mm x 1470 mm:

[image]

Will create an 530 mm x 1470 mm sized board. Verification with the inbuilt measurement tool (Ctrl + M).

[image]

Can be changed later:

> **View » Board Planning Mode**, commands that support interactively
>   changing the shape are available in this mode:
>
> - **Redefine Board Shape** - select this command to interactively draw a new shape.
> - **Move Board Vertices** - select this command to interactively modify the shape of the board by moving vertices or sliding the edges
>     of the shape.
> - **Move Board Shape** - select this command to move the complete board shape to a new location in the workspace. Note that this command
>     only moves the board shape, other objects that have been placed in the
>     workspace are not moved. To move the board shape as well as all placed
>     objects, select everything to be moved and use the **Edit » Move »
>     Move Selection** command (switch to 2D Layout Mode first). Taken from
>     [Altium Tech Doc](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Obj-BoardShape%28%28Board+Shape%29%29_AD).